# Data from Mongo db arrives later than data from a json file on server in Next js App

Tags: json, reactjs, mongodb, next.js

I have a form that currently uses data from a json file.

The data is retrieved like so

```
const categoryList = require('../data/categories.json');
```

I am changing this to retrieve data from an api which fetches data from mongodb.

```
http://localhost:3000/api/categories
```

The above link gives me same results as the json file.

```
import { getCategories } from '../../lib/hooks';
....

const PostEditor = () => {

  const [categories] = getCategories(); // this gives me all the categories from api as an array
  console.log("categories from db")
  console.log(categories)

  const catList = require('../data/categories.json'); // same result as above
  console.log("cat list from json file")
  console.log(catList)

  ...
  ...

  return (
    <>
    ...
    ...

          <Autocomplete
          multiple
          options={catList} // Data from db(categories field) does not reach here.
          limitTags={2}
```

From the above code, both console log from db and console log from the json file have same values in browser.
The console log in command prompt shows values from db as "undefined". I think the data from db is not reaching the page in time but from the json file it does.

How to solve this problem?

I use Next js.

Edit:
I moved the data fetching from Api into a parent component (directly under pages) and passed the categories as props to the child component

```
<PostEditor categories={cats}/>
```

Still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

As mongodb data is external, so it's taking time to load. You have to call asynchronously. Check like this:

```
const PostEditor = async() => {

  const [categories] = await getCategories(); 
  ...
}
```